# Why is this show called "Singapore Idol", not "Singaporean Idol"?

Tags: demonyms

In other cases, [a [country] Idol show](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idol_series#Idol_around_the_world) titles use the demonym: *American Idol*, *Malaysian Idol* or *Indonesian Idol*. Why is this show called [*Singapore Idol*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Idol), not *Singaporean Idol*?

Comment: Related: [Why do we say "Japan earthquake" and not "Japanese earthquake"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18248/why-do-we-say-japan-earthquake-and-not-japanese-earthquake)

Comment: I was inspired by that question, in fact.

Comment: Looking at the very list you linked, there are bunches of abnormalities. The simple answer: Marketing and name branding. Someone decides which title will work better. Until you find a comment by that person (or team), I highly doubt we will be able to answer this question.

Comment: @MrHen: Can't really get behind that mule. I bet the majority of fluent English speakers would make the same decision here as the actual Marketing guy. For the same reason(s). Iti is asking *why*. Presumably because he doesn't know and he's interested. F'x's suggestion is the only one here anyway - but it's had several upvotes, so maybe that's enough evidence to say we *have* identified, agreed upon, and given an answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Until you go poll the majority of English speakers, we _still_ cannot answer this question. We can make a very educated guess which is very likely correct, sure, but that isn't the same as finding the correct answer.

Comment: @MrHen: Well, obviously you don't need to poll the *majority* to get an answer - if you did, Mori, Gallup, etc. just wouldn't be economically feasible. Be that as it may, in the absence of any proffered alternatives I personally am happy enough with F'x's answer at the moment.

Answer (score 8):

Probably because “Singaporean Idol” is quite a mouthful! Shorter titles are more impressive, easier to communicate. I'm sure they run it by many communication experts…

Comment: Quite so. Which is doubtless why they have a *Dutch Idol* rather than *Netherlandish Idol*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But *Dutch* is the standard demonym of Netherlands, not *Netherlandish*.

Comment: Yes, but *why*? Netherlandish is a perfectly valid word, and all other things being equal it would be the default demonym (excellent word, btw). But we avoid it because it's such a mouthful.

Comment: Isn't Dutch a derogatory term - being a diminutive of Deutsch (ie little germans) ? Shouldn't the Netherlanderish be up in arms over the insult and rioting in the streets - or isn;t that a very dutch attitude!

Comment: @MartinBeckett, why would you think that Dutch is diminutive of Deutsch?

Comment: @Unreason - more accurately it's a 14C word for all Germans - it only later came to mean just Netherlands and the spelling separated

Answer (score 2):

Another theory, just as speculative:

When the place name ends in a vowel, like *America* or *Australia* or *Canada* or *India* or *Indonesia* or *Macedonia* or *Malaysia* or *Nigeria* or *Asia* or *Latin America*, it is slightly awkward to say phrases like "America Idol" or "Canada Idol", with two consecutive vowels. The phrases like *American Idol* and *Canadian Idol* roll more easily off the tongue. (This is the same phenomenon behind the article *a* becoming *an* before vowels in English, and behind [linking R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_r) and other related sandhi processes.)

Because *Singapore* ends in a consonant sound, there is no reason to use the longer adjectival form, and the place name can be used directly. In support of this theory, observe *Pakistan Idol* which is not turned into *Pakistani Idol*.

(This theory doesn't fully explain why *Greek Idol* instead of *Greece Idol*, and why *Hrvatski Idol* is fine, but it does explain why the adjectival forms are chosen even when they are longer, as in *Canadian Idol* over *Canada Idol*.)

Comment: Ture or not, I quite like analysis. PS. I'm a Singaporean.

Comment: An anonymous user suggested an edit to the last paragraph of this answer, which I'm placing as a comment: "why *Greek Idol* is accepted instead of *Greece Idol*? Because both *Greece* and *Greek* end in a consonant sound, so it is preferable to use the demonym […] why *Hrvatski Idol* is fine? because both *Hrvatska* (Croatia's native name) and *Hrvatski* (the demonym one) end in a vowel sound (although the vowels are different). And, The word *Idol* begins with the vowel 'a' sound. When two 'a' sounds comes together, that doesn't really sound good. So, the different vowel is preferable."

Answer (score 0):

There is a [question on travel.SE](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344/country-citizen-tags-convention-needed) at the moment that I think is similar.

Both questions may be formulated as: **Is a demonym a noun or an adjective?**

On Wikipedia we can find [a list of adjectival and demonymic forms of places](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectival_and_demonymic_forms_of_place_names#Countries_and_nations).

I would suggest a demonym is a noun, so saying *Singaporean Idol* (demonym) would be a mistake, while *Singapore Idol* (adjective) is the right form.

In the travel.SE question, the matter is whether we should say *New Zealander citizen* (demonym) or *New Zealand citizen* (adjective).